# Connecting to an MSSQL database through ODBC Error

Tags: php, iis-7, odbc

Where to start..

- I have a server with windows 2008 R2 standard 32 bits.
- On that server ISS 7 is installed and a php site is added but requires databases.
- Made an sql database on that server wich is called 'test'.
- ODBC connection is made and tested and it succeeded.
- Now when I use this php code to connect to the server it gives me:

  Can not connect because the target machine actively refused it.

php code:

```
<?
### Database    ###
$user = "*****"; //database user
$pass = "*****";    //database password
$host = "localhost";   //database location
$db = "test";     //database name
##mysql_connect ("$host","$user","$pass");
##mysql_select_db("$db");
$dbConn = odbc_connect("$db","$user","$pass","$host") or die(odbc_errormsg());
?>
```

The password and username are correct but the error still remains.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your datasource using administrative tools, data sources, System DSN?

if not i'm sure it won't find the database.

see this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305599